# allow entry of url which only starts with https:// but not with any other protocols in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.6

I want to enter url in database with only  `https://`but not with any other protocols.when adding form data in laravel-forms.I have tried with `^(https:\/\/)(www\.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]*[^\/]$` but it still stores the url with http:// also.
please suggest me how can i achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using html also with setting the **pattern** to input field like below

```
<input type="url" name="url" placeholder="https://example.com" pattern="https://.*"/>
```